# AddEntityFrameworkStores can only be called with a role that derives from IdentityRole in .NET Core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have changed a project from the .NET Core 1.1 to 2.0 version, but I'm getting an error from the Identity, when It tries to add the stores:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<long>>()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

The thrown error is:

> AddEntityFrameworkStores can only be called with a role that derives
>   from IdentityRole

These are my classes:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<long>
{
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<long>, long>        
{
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { 
        }
}
```

Someone could help me?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Same issue, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Long time since I asked this question, but here's how I deal with nowadays:

**Startup.cs**

```
services.AddIdentity<User, Role>()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders();
services.AddScoped<RoleManager<Role>>();
```

**Entites:**

```
public class User : IdentityUser<int>
{
}

public class Role : IdentityRole<int>
{
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For same issue, you can look at this:https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1364

Comment: very confusing link... veers off into so many tangents... I could not tell which was similar unless I dedicate the next hour of production development to wading through it

Answer (score 2):

First, Create these two classes as follow: (Custom entities)

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser<long>
{

}

public class AppRole : IdentityRole<long>
{
    public AppRole() : base()
    {

    }

    public AppRole(string roleName)
    {
        Name = roleName;
    }
}
```

Then change ConfigureServices function into Startup.cs file:

```
services.AddIdentity<AppUser, AppRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Finally, Create db class:

```
public class MyDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser,AppRole,long>
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options)
       : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
.AddDefaultTokenProviders()
.AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

if you put.AddRoles<IdentityUser >()
you will get the error, hence use <IdentityRole >