# How do I add support for and populate roles in Razor Pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-identity

I'm trying to figure out how to enable and populate roles in my Razor Pages application.

By following various tutorials, `ConfigureServices` in *Startup.cs* looks like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(
            Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options =>
        {
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
        })
        .AddRoles<ApplicationUser>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

    services.AddRazorPages();

    // Set the default authentication policy to require users to be authenticated
    services.AddControllers(config =>
    {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();
        config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    });
}
```

But the call to `AddDefaultIdentity` raises an exception.

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'AddEntityFrameworkStores can only be called with a role that derives from IdentityRole.'

Can anyone see what I'm missing here? Also, I really want to know how to populate the roles.

Comment: It's very similar on your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56466438/12282249

Comment: @DenisStukalov: I did see that one. But he's using a bunch of different methods than the ones created by Visual Studio, and I don't know why. I can't find a good tutorial on this stuff.

Comment: It sould be `.AddRoles<IdentityRole>()` instead of IdentityUser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `IdentityUser` to `IdentityRole` like below:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options =>
        {
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
        })
        .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()  //change this
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-3.1#add-role-services-to-identity

Comment: That works, thanks. Have any good examples of populating my application's roles?

Comment: Hi @JonathanWood,What do you mean for population your roles?Populate them to the database?Refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60594245/11398810).Or populate the roles in the selectlist?

Comment: The link to "here" seems to deal only with users and not roles or user roles

Answer (score 0):

You might be confusing your custom roles in the application (Admin, Manager, etc) with IdentityUser.

`IdentityUser` is the basic model for the User records in the application.

If you want to add custom properties to the User model then create a new class that inherits from `IdentityUser` and add new properties. This new class is often called `ApplicationUser` but can be called anything you want.

[Docs on customizing user model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model)

I recommend following one tutorial. Here is one from the Microsoft documentation that goes through a number of scenarios and has source code as well.

[Official tutorial on authorization and roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/secure-data)

Comment: I thought `IdentityUser` was the basic model for user records in the application?

Comment: Yes you're right. I've corrected the answer, thanks @JonathanWood